# Path to static image file modified to Orbeon resource protocol (oxf)

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm using XInclude to import several forms as tabs on a multi-tabbed container form (using fr:tabbable and fr:tab). I am importing the model, binds, resources and body of each sub-form.

One of the components on a tab is an XBL component containing an HTML img element pointing to a static png image file. The image is displayed ok when the sub-form is published and invoked on its own, but when imported on to the multi-tabbed form the image link is broken.

When inspecting the source, the path to the image in the /xbl folder has been modified to  include the oxf:/  protocol.

In addition, there is logic on the xbl form control to make it non-relevant when the form is loaded and depends on a checkbox to make it relevant. When the logic is removed, the image is displayed.

**I have done some more testing and confirm that the problem occurs when enabling non-relevant controls on a form which has been imported via xinclude.**

Orbeon is also in persistence mode using the CRUD REST api to save and publish forms as text files.

Is there anything I can do to make sure the image path is initialised when it is non-relevant?

Many thanks,

---

Import.xhtml

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
         xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
         xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
         xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
         xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
         xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title>Import Test</xh:title>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
            <!-- Main instance -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
                <form>
                    <xi:include href="oxf:/forms/Testing/FootMapTest/form/form.xhtml"
                                xpointer="xpath(//form/*)"/>
                </form>
            </xf:instance>
            <!-- Bindings -->
            <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
                <xi:include href="oxf:/forms/Testing/FootMapTest/form/form.xhtml"
                            xpointer="xpath(//xf:model/xf:bind[@id='fr-form-binds']/*)"/>
            </xf:bind>
            <!-- Metadata -->
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <metadata>
                    <application-name>Testing</application-name>
                    <form-name>ImportTest</form-name>
                    <title xml:lang="en">Import Test</title>
                    <description xml:lang="en"/>
                </metadata>
            </xf:instance>
            <!-- Attachments -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <attachments>
                    <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                    <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
                </attachments>
            </xf:instance>
            <!-- All form resources -->
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-resources" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <resources>
                    <resource xml:lang="en">
                        <xi:include href="oxf:/forms/Testing/FootMapTest/form/form.xhtml"
                                    xpointer="xpath(//resources/resource[@xml:lang='en']/*)"/>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </xf:instance>
            <!-- Utility instances for services -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <request/>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <response/>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:view>
            <fr:body xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                     xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                     xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
                <fr:tabbable>
                    <fr:tab>
                        <fr:label>Tab 1</fr:label>
                        <xi:include href="oxf:/forms/Testing/FootMapTest/form/form.xhtml"
                                    xpointer="xpath(//xh:body/fr:view/fr:body/*)"/>
                    </fr:tab>
                </fr:tabbable>
            </fr:body>
        </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

FootMapTest.xhtml

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
         xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
         xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
         xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
         xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
         xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title>FootMap Test</xh:title>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
            <!-- Main instance -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
                <form>
                    <section-1>
                        <showFoot/>
                        <control-2/>
                    </section-1>
                </form>
            </xf:instance>
            <!-- Bindings -->
            <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
                <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                    <xf:bind id="control-2-bind" ref="control-2" name="control-2"
                             relevant="$showFoot=true()"/>
                    <xf:bind id="showFoot-bind" ref="showFoot" name="showFoot" type="xf:boolean"/>
                </xf:bind>
            </xf:bind>
            <!-- Metadata -->
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <metadata>
                    <application-name>Testing</application-name>
                    <form-name>FootMapTest</form-name>
                    <title xml:lang="en">FootMap Test</title>
                    <description xml:lang="en"/>
                </metadata>
            </xf:instance>
            <!-- Attachments -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <attachments>
                    <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                    <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
                </attachments>
            </xf:instance>
            <!-- All form resources -->
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-resources" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <resources>
                    <resource xml:lang="en">
                        <showFoot>
                            <label>Show Foot?</label>
                            <hint/>
                        </showFoot>
                        <control-2>
                            <label/>
                            <hint/>
                        </control-2>
                        <section-1>
                            <label>Untitled Section</label>
                        </section-1>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </xf:instance>
            <!-- Utility instances for services -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <request/>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <response/>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:view>
            <fr:body xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                     xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                     xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
                <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                    <fr:grid>
                        <xh:tr>
                            <xh:td>
                                <fr:yesno-input xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                                xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                                                id="showFoot-control"
                                                bind="showFoot-bind">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/showFoot/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/showFoot/hint"/>
                                    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                </fr:yesno-input>
                            </xh:td>
                            <xh:td>
                                <nhs:footmap xmlns:nhs="http://www.wales.nhs.uk/"
                                             xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
                                             xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                                             xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                             side="left"
                                             siteselect=""
                                             missingtoes=""
                                             testorder=""
                                             id="control-2-control"
                                             bind="control-2-bind">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-2/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-2/hint"/>
                                    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                </nhs:footmap>
                            </xh:td>
                        </xh:tr>
                    </fr:grid>
                </fr:section>
            </fr:body>
        </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

footmap.xbl

```
<xbl:xbl xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
         xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
         xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
         xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
         xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
         xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
         xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
         xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:nhs="http://www.wales.nhs.uk/">

    <xbl:script src="/xbl/nhs/footmap/footmap.js"/>

    <xbl:binding id="nhs-footmap" element="nhs|footmap"
            xxf:external-events="nhs-footmap-updated nhs-footmap-refresh"
            xxbl:mode="lhha binding value extenal-value focus"
            xxbl:container="span">
        <metadata xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
            <display-name lang="en">Foot Map</display-name>
            <icon lang="en">
                <small-icon>/apps/fr/style/images/silk/image.png</small-icon>
                <large-icon>/apps/fr/style/images/silk/image.png</large-icon>
            </icon>
            <templates>
                <view>
                    <nhs:footmap side="left" siteselect=""  missingtoes="" testorder="">
                        <xf:label ref=""/>
                        <xf:hint ref=""/>
                        <xf:help ref=""/>
                        <xf:alert ref=""/>
                   </nhs:footmap>
                </view>
            </templates>
            <control-details>
              <xf:select1 ref="@side">
                <xf:label>Side:</xf:label>
                <xf:hint>Which foot?</xf:hint>
                <xf:item>
                    <xf:label>Left</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>left</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:item>
                    <xf:label>Right</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>right</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
              </xf:select1>
              <xf:select ref="@siteselect" appearance="full">
                <xf:label>Sites:</xf:label>
                <xf:hint>Which sites?</xf:hint>
                <xf:item selected="true">
                    <xf:label>Big Toe (1):</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>1</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:item selected="true">
                    <xf:label>Middle Toe (3):</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>3</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:item selected="true">
                    <xf:label>Little Toe (5):</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>5</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:item selected="false">
                    <xf:label>Plantar</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>6</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:item selected="false">
                    <xf:label>Medial</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>7</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:item selected="false">
                    <xf:label>Lateral</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>8</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
              </xf:select>
              <xf:select ref="@missingtoes" appearance="full">
                <xf:label>Missing Toes:</xf:label>
                <xf:hint>Which toes are missing?</xf:hint>
                <xf:item selected="false">
                    <xf:label>Big Toe (1):</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>1</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:item selected="false">
                    <xf:label>Index Toe (2):</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>2</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:item selected="false">
                    <xf:label>Middle Toe (3):</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>3</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:item selected="false">
                    <xf:label>Fourth Toe (4):</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>4</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
                <xf:item selected="false">
                    <xf:label>Little Toe (5):</xf:label>
                    <xf:value>5</xf:value>
                </xf:item>
              </xf:select>
              <xf:input ref="@testorder">
                <xf:label>Test Order (json):</xf:label>
                <xf:hint>What order should sites be tested?</xf:hint>
              </xf:input>
            </control-details>
        </metadata>

        <xbl:resources>
            <xbl:style src="/xbl/nhs/footmap/footmap.css"/>
        </xbl:resources>

        <xbl:handlers>
            <xbl:handler event="nhs-footmap-updated" phase="target">
                <!-- <xf:message level="modal">
                    <xf:output value="event('states')" />
                </xf:message> -->

                <xf:var name="jsonstates" select="event('states')" />
                <xf:setvalue ref="xxf:binding('nhs-footmap')" value="$jsonstates" />
            </xbl:handler>

            <xbl:handler type="javascript" ev:event="xforms-enabled" phase="target">
                  ORBEON.xforms.XBL.instanceForControl(this).updateAreas();
            </xbl:handler>

            <xbl:handler type="javascript" ev:event="xforms-disabled" phase="target">
                    //ORBEON.xforms.XBL.instanceForControl(this).hide();
            </xbl:handler>


            <!-- <xbl:handler type="javascript" event="nhs-footmap-refresh" phase="target">
                ORBEON.xforms.XBL.instanceForControl(this).updateAreas();
            </xbl:handler> -->

            <xbl:handler type="javascript" event="xforms-value-changed" phase="target">
                ORBEON.xforms.XBL.instanceForControl(this).updateAreas();
            </xbl:handler>
        </xbl:handlers>


        <xbl:template xxbl:transform="oxf:unsafe-xslt">
            <xsl:transform version="2.0">
                <xsl:import href="oxf:/oxf/xslt/utils/xbl.xsl"/>
                <xsl:template match="/*">

                    <xf:group class="nhs-footmap-container">

                        <xf:model id="footmap-model">
                            <xf:instance id="areastates">
                                <json type="object">
                                    <data/>
                                </json>
                            </xf:instance>
                            <xf:instance id="local">
                                <model>
                                    <side/>
                                    <areas/>
                                </model>
                            </xf:instance>
                        </xf:model>

                        <!-- Variable pointing to external single-node binding -->
                        <xf:var name="binding" value="xxf:binding('nhs-footmap')"/>
                        <xf:var name="binding-context" value="xxf:binding-context('nhs-footmap')"/>
                        <xf:var name="local" value="instance('local')"/>
                        <xf:var name="view" value="exf:readonly($binding) and property('xxf:readonly-appearance') = 'static'"/>

                        <xsl:copy-of select="xxbl:parameter(., 'side')"/>
                        <xf:var name="leftFoot" value="$side = 'left'" />
                        <xf:var name="rightFoot" value="$side = 'right'" />
                        <xf:setvalue ref="instance('local')/side" value="{{$side}}" />

                        <xf:var name="requestPath" select="xxf:get-request-path()" />

                        <xsl:copy-of select="xxbl:parameter(., 'siteselect')"/>
                        <xf:var name="toe1" value="tokenize($siteselect, '\s+') = '1'" />
                        <xf:var name="toe3" value="tokenize($siteselect, '\s+') = '3'" />
                        <xf:var name="toe5" value="tokenize($siteselect, '\s+') = '5'" />
                        <xf:var name="plantar" value="tokenize($siteselect, '\s+') = '6'" />
                        <xf:var name="medial" value="tokenize($siteselect, '\s+') = '7'" />
                        <xf:var name="lateral" value="tokenize($siteselect, '\s+') = '8'" />

                        <xsl:copy-of select="xxbl:parameter(., 'missingtoes')"/>
                        <xf:var name="missing-toe1" value="tokenize($missingtoes, '\s+') = '1'" />
                        <xf:var name="missing-toe2" value="tokenize($missingtoes, '\s+') = '2'" />
                        <xf:var name="missing-toe3" value="tokenize($missingtoes, '\s+') = '3'" />
                        <xf:var name="missing-toe4" value="tokenize($missingtoes, '\s+') = '4'" />
                        <xf:var name="missing-toe5" value="tokenize($missingtoes, '\s+') = '5'" />

                        <xsl:copy-of select="xxbl:parameter(., 'testorder')"/>
                        <xf:var name="notestorder" value="string-length($testorder)=0" />

                        <!--<xf:group id="component-group" ref="$binding[not($view)]">-->
                        <xf:group id="component-group" ref="$binding">

                            <xf:input ref="$binding" id="nhs-footmap-states" class="nhs-footmap-states" />

                            <xh:div class="xbl-nhs-footmap-imagemap-div nhs-footmap-imgsize">
                                <xh:img class="nhs-footmap-footimage" src="/xbl/nhs/footmap/img/{{$side}}foot.png" usemap="#foot-imagemap-{{$side}}" />

                                <xf:group ref=".[$toe1 and not($missing-toe1)]">
                                    <xh:a href="#" data-value="N" class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-toe1 nhs-footmap-site"> <xh:span class="badge">N</xh:span></xh:a>
                                </xf:group>
                                <xf:group ref=".[$missing-toe1]">
                                    <xh:a href="#" data-value="-" class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-toe1 nhs-footmap-site toe-missing"> <xh:span class="badge"><xh:i class="icon-minus icon-white"/></xh:span></xh:a>
                                </xf:group>

                                <xf:group ref=".[$toe3 and not($missing-toe3)]">
                                    <xh:a href="#" data-value="N" class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-toe3 nhs-footmap-site"> <xh:span class="badge">N</xh:span> </xh:a>
                                </xf:group>
                                <xf:group ref=".[$missing-toe3]">
                                    <xh:a href="#" data-value="-" class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-toe3 nhs-footmap-site toe-missing"> <xh:span class="badge"><xh:i class="icon-minus icon-white"/></xh:span></xh:a>
                                </xf:group>

                                <xf:group ref=".[$toe5 and not($missing-toe5)]">
                                    <xh:a href="#" data-value="N" class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-toe5 nhs-footmap-site"> <xh:span class="badge">N</xh:span> </xh:a>
                                </xf:group>
                                <xf:group ref=".[$missing-toe5]">
                                    <xh:a href="#" data-value="-" class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-toe5 nhs-footmap-site toe-missing"> <xh:span class="badge"><xh:i class="icon-minus icon-white"/></xh:span></xh:a>
                                </xf:group>

                                <xf:group ref=".[$plantar]">
                                    <xh:a href="#" data-value="N" class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-toe6 nhs-footmap-site"> <xh:span class="badge">N</xh:span> </xh:a>
                                </xf:group>

                                <xf:group ref=".[$medial]">
                                    <xh:a href="#" data-value="N" class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-toe7 nhs-footmap-site"> <xh:span class="badge">N</xh:span> </xh:a>
                                </xf:group>

                                <xf:group ref=".[$lateral]">
                                    <xh:a href="#" data-value="N" class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-toe8 nhs-footmap-site"> <xh:span class="badge">N</xh:span> </xh:a>
                                </xf:group>


                                <xf:group ref=".[not($notestorder)]">
                                    <xh:span class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-testorder1 nhs-footmap-testorder badge" />
                                    <xh:span class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-testorder3 nhs-footmap-testorder badge" />
                                    <xh:span class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-testorder5 nhs-footmap-testorder badge" />
                                    <xh:span class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-testorder6 nhs-footmap-testorder badge" />
                                    <xh:span class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-testorder7 nhs-footmap-testorder badge" />
                                    <xh:span class="nhs-footmap-{{$side}}-testorder8 nhs-footmap-testorder badge" />
                                </xf:group>                             
                            </xh:div>

                            <!--<xf:trigger id="resetButton">
                                <xf:label>Reset</xf:label>
                                <xf:action type="javascript" event="DOMActivate">
                                    ORBEON.xforms.XBL.instanceForControl(this).reset();
                                </xf:action>
                            </xf:trigger>-->

                            <!--<xf:trigger id="absentButton">
                                <xf:label>Absent</xf:label>
                                <xf:action type="javascript" event="DOMActivate">
                                    ORBEON.xforms.XBL.instanceForControl(this).absent();
                                </xf:action>
                            </xf:trigger>-->                            


                            <!-- Properties -->
                        </xf:group>

                        <!-- <xf:group ref="$binding[$view]"/> -->
                    </xf:group>
                </xsl:template>
            </xsl:transform>
        </xbl:template>
    </xbl:binding>
</xbl:xbl>
```

Comment: This might be a bug. Would you be able to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, so we can run it here and investigate this further? If you manage to do this, I'd recommend you then update your question with a link to that example, and post a follow-up comment here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll put together an example for you to investigate and I'll post it on here.

Comment: @avernet I have added the three main files which will enable you to replicate the problem.  I have not included the javascript, css and image files for the footmap. The images are left and right feet.

Comment: Sorry @jtb, it looks like I missed your last comment. Have you figured this out since then?

Comment: Hi @avernet, I have not resolved the root cause. However I have been able to use a workaround by hiding/showing the control using javascript/css instead of using the relevant bind attribute.

Comment: Got it @jtb. Then, since you have a workaround, I guess we'll leave this one as-is. And of course, just let us know of this comes back, and you need a solution. In that case, of course, we'll investigate this further.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your interest @avernet